# ES6 class inheritance without "extends" keyword

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, ecmascript-6

I'd like to do inheritance in an es6 class without the `extends` keyword:

Typical approach:

```
class Foo extends Bar {
  contructor() {
    ...
  }
}
```

What I am looking for is to generate an object with the same signature but using this pattern:

```
class Foo {
  contructor(Bar) {
    // use Bar class somehow
    ...
  }
}
```

Thanks

== EDITS ==

Context:

I build an extension (`ami`) for a JS library `threejs`.
It provides new objects that seamlessly work in `threejs`.

Problem:

`threejs` has an internal mechanism to generate unique ids for each object, that is critical for its proper behavior.

Current implementations rely on `three` to be exposed as a global variable, so anybody that creates an object must reference it to ensure the ids are actually unique.

```
// in ami
// ID of this object will be unique accros all classes
// that are based of global THREE.Mesh
class Foo extends THREE.Mesh {
  contructor() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Using global variable works fine but I want to get rid of the global namespace requirement.

If I do not reference the same base elements in `ami` and in my application, id can conflict.

```
// in ami
import {Mesh} from 'three';

class Foo extends Mesh {
  contructor() {
    ...
  }
}

// in my app
import {Foo} from 'ami';
imoport {Mesh} from 'three';

const foo = new Foo(); // it uses "Mesh" from ami as a base.
const mesh = new Mesh(); // it uses current "Mesh" as a base.
// IDs will conflict...
```

One solution that could work is that I provide a new argument in `ami` constructors, to provide the `three` reference:

```
// in ami
class Foo {
  contructor(mesh) {
    ...
  }
}

// in my app
imoport {Mesh} from 'three';
import {Foo} from 'ami';

const foo = new Foo(Mesh);
const mesh = new Mesh();
```

But I do not know how to implement this solution.

Comment: WTH do you want to do that? Of course you can always do inheritance explicitly in ES5-style, but that totally defeats the purpose of the `class` syntax.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you know about how `extends` works, as in, what are the things that need to be done?

Comment: What exactly do you understand by "*an object with the same signature*"? Please post your expectations with a demo instance, e.g. showing what results `instanceof`, method calls and in general the inheritance chain are expected to give.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for composition over inheritance? Just do `this.inner = new Bar`.

Comment: Don't you need to clone objects instead? What is your REAL need? Isn't your question an illustration of XY problem? See http://xyproblem.info

Comment: Thanks for feedback, added more details in the question -

Comment: What is "ami", is that important or just the name of your extension?

Comment: `Mesh` inherits from `Object3D` which [doesn't do anything weird](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/9b7e901438e662e002979a3c78e338eedb0ce2ec/src/core/Object3D.js#L24) about the uuids. It sounds like your codebase is messed up so that using `import … from 'three'` resolves to two different instances of the three.js library. Fix your module loader/bundler, instead of rewriting the code.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer addresses the question as originally posed and was good enough to help the OP refine the question and garner immediate upvotes. I'd appreciate it if you didn't downvote it merely because the goalposts have moved.*

Assuming that you are not crazy and this is a learning exercise, the best way to learn how to implement this is to get Typescript, write a class using extends, compile it with ES5 as the target, and look at the generated JavaScript. Ensure your base class has methods, properties, static methods, static properties, and a constructor with mixed required and optional parameters. Then derive another class from it and override some methods and replace some. You'll see how it's done by people who got serious about it.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, added more details in the question -

Comment: Cleaning out the global namespace is something that the writers of the Aurelia SPA framework did in such a way that _everything_ is removed and it can sometimes be a bit of a mission to figure out how to bring things back _into_ scope. I cannot myself do the revised question justice, but I strongly advise you to engage with Aurelia's authors at https://gitter.im/aurelia/Discuss where you can encourage them to respond to this question on stack overflow. You might also search for "Aurelia threejs" because it's possible this specific problem has already been solved.